# automatically add node to href in query and cancel default

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

This is probably so simple to someone but cant figure it out. I have this code that  shows a node in an alert box. How do I add this to the nodes href value ie www.example.com/connector/(nodes number). Also there seems to be a prevent default somehere that stops click events. How do I remove that?. Is there a simple way in jquery.

The code I have is below.

```
$("#demo")
    .bind("select_node.jstree", function (event, data) {
                       var selectedObj = data.rslt.obj;
        alert(selectedObj.attr("id") + selectedObj.attr("data"));
```

This produces the alert with node number.

From the source code I need to add to the href value below.

```
     <li id="node_80" rel="folder" class="jstree-closed"><ins class="jstree-icon">&nbsp;</ins><a href="#" class="jstree-clicked"><ins class="jstree-icon">&nbsp;</ins>TEST</a></li>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
$("#demo")
    .bind("select_node.jstree", function (event, data) {
          var selectedObj = data.rslt.obj;
 $('.jstree-clicked').attr("href","www.example.com/connector/"+selectedObj.attr("id"));
          ...
```

Comment: BRILLIANT. Thanks it worked. Is there any way that I can make the node clickable. There seems to be a return false that is applied to it somewhere. Can I reverse that easily.

Comment: I found the prevent default function, and removed and that now works, so ignore last question.. However it adds eg &id=node_80 at the end. How can I remove node_. Is there an easy method.

Comment: you can do a str.replace('node_','')

Comment: Hi. I tried that and it does not work. Where abouts would I put this. thanks.

Comment: I managed to get this working, by using jquery replace. adding .replace("node_","") ie selectedObjx.attr("id").replace("node_","")); I have added this in case anyone has similar problems. Many thanks for everyones help.

Comment: Glad you managed to come right, can you mark this as the correct answer please. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

With thanks to Manatok.

I managed to get this working, by using jquery replace. adding

```
 .replace("node_","") ie selectedObjx.attr("id").replace("node_",""));
```

I have added this in case anyone has similar problems. Many thanks for everyones help. – user1074541 Feb 27 at 22:03